# How to reliably compare the integer or float values of a list?

Tags: list, compare, operators, ocaml

Suppose I have int lists `[1; 2; 3]` and `[4; 3; 5]`, where each is a digit in a number.

Playing around on OCaml I see that:
`[1; 2; 3] > [4; 3; 5];;` evaluates to `false`,
while `[1; 2; 3] < [4; 3; 5];;` evaluates to `true`.

With lists of different lengths...
`[4; 5] > [1;2;3]` and `[4; 5] > [1;9;3]`
evaluate to `TRUE`, which is weird.

It looks like it's comparing each individual element and if one pair doesn't satisfy the inequality then it returns `false`, but if the lists aren't of the same length it only compares the corresponding elements that it can compare and ignores the rest.

However, I check the List module and pervasive module and I can't find any documentation specifying exactly how this function works.

Can someone categorically confirm, add to, or contradict what I've already deduced?

Answer (score 4):

For lists of simple values (like integers and characters), the polymorphic comparison uses "lexicographic order." It works like the order of words in the dictionary. In essence, start at the beginning of the lists and compare corresponding elements until they are different. Then the comparison depends on the order of the two differing elements. If you reach the end of one list before the other (with no differences up to that point), the shorter list is less than the longer. If you reach the end of both lists at the same time (with no differences up to that point), the lists are equal.

Following this same set of rules, "the" appears before "then" in the dictionary, and "then" appears after "them". You can verify this using OCaml lists `['t'; 'h'; 'e']`, `['t'; 'h'; 'e'; 'n']`; `['t'; 'h'; 'e'; 'm']`.

However, when I have researched this carefully I've found that the OCaml polymorphic comparison function for structured values (like lists, records, etc.) is not defined. The only thing you can really count on is that it is consistent.

The documentation of the [Pervasives module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) says only this:

> These functions coincide with the usual orderings over integers, characters, strings, byte sequences and floating-point numbers, and extend them to a total ordering over all types. The ordering is compatible with ( = ). As in the case of ( = ), mutable structures are compared by contents. Comparison between functional values raises `Invalid_argument`. Comparison between cyclic structures may not terminate.

If you need a certain order you should write your own comparison function.